# Press event preventing pan responder - React Native

Tags: react-native

I have an animated component(Animation) which its sole purpose is to swipe its content left and right horizontally.

Inside my Animation component I have a few buttons as its children. See below:

```
<Animation onSwipeRight={backMonth} onSwipeLeft={advanceMonth}>
    <Button onPress={select}/>
    <Button onPress={select}/>
    <Button onPress={select}/>
    <Button onPress={select}/>
</Animation>
```

I realized that the button press takes preference, preventing the swipe animation to happen.

What I wanted to happen, is that on a longPress the pan responder would always swipe the buttons(even when I press one of them while trying to swipe), otherwise on quick button presses, each button individually would call its selection callback after I release my finger.